# Error al generar document con jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de generar un documento de la siguiente manera:

Tengo un ajax y la respuesta que debe venir en código html quiero recrearla en ventana aparte eh imprimirla:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST", async: false, url: "index.php", data: data,
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                //generamos el documento
                printWindow = window.open('', 'Interface de Impresion');
                printWindow.document.write(response);
                printWindow.document.close();
            }
        });
```

**Actualización**

profundizando en el código al parecer de las siguientes dos lineas la segunda intenta acceder a la propiedad document, y no existe, como es posible si con la primera linea se crea el objeto.

```
printWindow = window.open('','Interface de Impresion');
printWindow.document.write(response); //Linea del Error
```

Pero me carga el siguiente Error algunas veces; a veces carga correctamente:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null
```

Comment: ¿En algunas veces te bloquea el pop up tu navegador? Si es así, aquí hay una solución que podría ayudarte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup

Comment: Tengo add block instalado y corriendo pero nunca me sale algo referente a bloqueo o reporte, ya lo he probado sin y con el pluggin y sigue presentándome el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día, yo genero reportes con html, de la siguiente manera:
(solo que habré una ventana emergente)

```
var report
report = window.open('report.html','reporte','width=612,     
height=1038,scrollbars=YES')
report.document.write("tu response");
```

Espero que te sirva de algo. Saludos.

Comment: no lo resuelve ...